# How to get a tag-specific custom Javascript function called from a jQuery click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of HTML toggle (two-state) widgets. I declare them in my HTML like this:

```
<div class='togglewidget'></div>
<div class='togglewidget'></div>
```

This looks nice because it is clean and simple.

Then I use jQuery to fill in the elements that make the widgets actually look like they are supposed to. I also attach a function to click events:

```
$(".togglewidget").append("/* stuff to make the widget work */");
$(".togglewidget").click(function() {toggleWidget(this);});
```

The toggleWidget() function does animation and handles state change. This all works great.

What I want is to add a custom function to each widget that gets called from the toggleWidget() function depending on state. I would like something like this:

```
<div class='togglewidget' customfunc='clicked1'></div>
<div class='togglewidget' customfunc='clicked2'></div>

function toggleWidget(this) {
    var widget = $(s);
    if (/* check for toggle state */) {
        // state change of widget is animated (I know how to do this)
        ...
        // call custom function for this individual widget (how to do this?)
        widget.GetCustomFunc(true);
    } else {
        // state change of widget is animated (I know how to do this)
        ...
        // call custom function for this individual widget (how to do this?)
        widget.GetCustomFunc(false)
    }
}
```

Then I define clicked1() for the first widget and clicked2() for the second widget. Each widget animates correctly based on behavior in toggleWidget, and clicked() and clicked2() define what actually happens when the individual widget is toggled.

What is the best way of doing this?

I think I could add an onClick="" to each togglewidget div, but then I don't have easy access to the state of the widget, and ordering might be an issue. I think the idea of having a "customfunc" property of the tag might work, but I think that would not validate as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the customfunc attribute using jquery:

```
if($(this).attr('customfunc')) =='customfunc1') {

}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function toggleWidget(this) {
    var widget = $(s);
    if ( /* check for toggle state */ ) {
        // state change of widget is animated (I know how to do this)
        ...
        // call custom function for this individual widget (how to do this?)

        var cufn = widget.attr('customfun');
        if ($.isFunction(widget[cufn])) {
            widget[cufn]();
        }
        widget.GetCustomFunc(true);
    } else {
        // state change of widget is animated (I know how to do this)
        ...
        // call custom function for this individual widget (how to do this?)
        var cufn = widget.attr('customfun');
        if ($.isFunction(widget[cufn])) {
            widget[cufn]();
        }
        widget.GetCustomFunc(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function toggleWidget(this) {
    var widget = $(s);
    var indexOfWidget = $('.togglewidget').index($(this));

    // for example to add custom property
    $(this).attr('customFunc', 'onClick' + indexOfWidget); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fun=$(this).attr('customfunc');
if(fun){
  eval(fun+"()");
}
```

This will call any function returned by "customfunc" attr